# pyqt5 cannot install with python 3.5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I installed python 3.5 then install pyqt5.5.1, when installing the binary file under win7, it showed warning that it's built under python3.4.I installed to the python35 directory anyway.I can open Assistant in start menu.But in python it's not working:

> from PyQt5.QtCore import * Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in 
>       from PyQt5.QtCore import * ImportError: DLL load failed

Comment: pyqt5.5.1 works with python 3.4.x and does not support python 3.5. You'll have to wait for an official release that target this version (probably the very next version) or compile one by yourself.

Comment: That's not entirely true. The binary package doesn't work with python3.5 because as he said it has been built under python3.4, but you can compile PyQt5 yourself and install it under python3.5.

Comment: Thanks guys, i use python3.4 and solved.

Answer (score 0):

**Use pip to install the Windows wheel file**

The installer were based on 3.4. So you can't use it.

[Download LINK](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5)

Command line guide: pip install name_of_file.whl

PS: install SIP in the same way.

Comment: Wheel files were removed by riverbank.